# Raspberry pi 3 Model B no autoconnect wifi when I shutdown

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I have a problem with raspberry pi 3, Model B conecting Wifi. I have the raspberry 3 display 7" where I can see if wifi is connected.

When disconnect and reconnect the ethernet cable, wifi works.  When I reboot with

```
sudo reboot
```

wifi works perfectly too, and I can reboot like this whenever I want and wifi works.

However, when I reboot using

```
sudo shutdown
```

and then power cycling the RPi, wifi doesn't work.

The file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
 network={
    ssid="My_wifi_name"
    psk="Password"
}
```

Some idea?

Comment: You say that you can reboot whenever you want and wifi works, but that when the raspberry shutdown and wake up wifi doesn't work. I'm not sure what you mean by shutdown/wakeup and how that differs from reboot.

Comment: That's the question, when I do `sudo shutdown` and after I put on raspberry the wifi isn't autoconnect to wifi. And I don't know why but when I reboot `sudo reboot` wifi works fine. What's difference between reboot and shutdown/wake up to wifi autoconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, thanks KDM for try help.

I solve it editing file /etc/network/interfaces and code:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-ssid "Your Network SSID"
   wpa-psk "Your Password"
```

Comment: This will work (only because you use of `dhcp` disables  `dhcpcd`) but this is a poor solution. You would be better to use the recommended default, which is more robust. See  [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)